# Problem with multi-columns using Grid

Tags: list-manipulation, grid-layouts, output-formatting

I am working on a data table,

```
Res = {351020, 332640, 315320, 298990, 283600, 269080, 255380,242460,230260,218730,207850,197560,187840,178650,169950,161730,153950,146580,139610,133000,126740,120810,115190,109850,104800,100000,95447,91126,87022,83124,79422,75903,72560,69380,66356,63480,60743,58138,55658,53297,51048,48905,46863,44917,43062,41292,39605,37995,36458,34991,33591,32253,30976,29756,28590,27475,26409,25390,24415,23483,22590,21736,20919,20136,19386,18668,17980,17321,16689,16083,15502,14945,14410,13897,13405,12932,12479,12043,11625,11223,10837,10467,10110,9767.2,9437.7,9120.8,8816.0,8522.7,8240.6,7969.1,7707.7,7456.2,7214.0,6980.6,6755.9,6539.4,6330.8,6129.8,5936.1,5749.3,5569.3}

Tem = Range[0, 100]

data1 = {Res, Tem}\[Transpose];

Text@Grid[Prepend[data1, {"Resistencia [\[CapitalOmega]]", 
"Temperatura \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\([\), \(\[Degree]\)]\)C]"}],Background -> {None, {Lighter[Yellow, .9], {White,Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .8]}}},Dividers -> {{Darker[Gray, .6], {Lighter[Gray, .5]},Darker[Gray, .6]}, {Darker[Gray, .6], Darker[Gray, .6], {False},Darker[Gray, .6]}}, Alignment ->{{Center, Center, {Left}}},ItemSize -> {{11, 11}}, Frame -> Darker[Black, .10],ItemStyle -> 14, Spacings -> {Automatic, .8}]
```

but this table is too long, I would like to do it in three columns, but I do not know how.

like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = Ceiling[Length[Res]/3];
m = Flatten /@ Transpose[Partition[MapIndexed[{#1, #2[[1]] - 1} &, Res],
    n, n, {1, 1}, {{"", ""}}]];
Grid[Prepend[m, Flatten@ConstantArray[
  {"Res\n[\[CapitalOmega]]", "Temp\n\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\([\), \(\[Degree]\)]\)C]"},
  3]], Background -> {None, {Lighter[Yellow, .9],
  {White, Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .8]}}},
 Dividers -> {{Darker[Gray, .6], {Lighter[Gray, .5]},
  Darker[Gray, .6]}, {Darker[Gray, .6],
  Darker[Gray, .6], {False}, Darker[Gray, .6]}},
 Alignment -> Center, ItemSize -> {{9, 5, 9, 5, 9, 5}},
 Frame -> Darker[Black, .10], ItemStyle -> 14,
 Spacings -> {Automatic, .8}]
```

Comment: thanks a lot Chris